# How do I map geom_label_repel to a color in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I make a boxplot of a dataset. A new person is introduced, and i want to plot this person on the existing dataset with geom_label_repel. However, color is not considered (probably because its different dataset).

Is there a way to do plot Lisa with the color from the old dataset?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

xDF <- data.frame(age=c(20,22,25,27,44, 34, 28, 32) ,
                 sex = c("F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M"),
                 Home_city =c("NY", "LA","NY", "LA", "LA", "LA","NY","NY") )

new_person <- data.frame(age=40, sex="F", Home_city="NY", name= "Lisa")

 ggplot(data=xDF, aes(x=Home_city, y=age, color=sex))+
     geom_boxplot()+
     geom_label_repel(data=new_person, aes(x=Home_city, y=age, color=sex, label=name),
               box.padding   = 0.35, 
               point.padding = 0.5,
               segment.color = 'grey50')
```

Comment: I see name Lisa colored red and the legend says this is a sex=Female. What am I missing here?

Comment: Lisa is in the middle of the NY axis. Lisa should be nuged to the Female side on the NY axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two problem, first you need to "dodge" the labels like boxplot and this is done using `position=position_dodge2(width=..)`, and adjust the width inside this argument because with geom_repel() it's unclear where you wanna position it. For example code below works for 2 labels(M+F):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

new_2p <- data.frame(age=c(40,40), sex=c("F","M"), 
Home_city="NY", name= "Lisa")

ggplot(data=xDF, aes(x=Home_city, y=age, color=sex))+
geom_boxplot()+
geom_label_repel(data=new_2p, aes(label=name),show.legend=FALSE,
               position = position_dodge2(width = 0.5),
               box.padding   = 0.35, 
               point.padding = 0.5,
               segment.color = 'grey50')
```

[image]

However you have an issue, because there's only 1 label, so it doesn't know how to "dodge", one quick fix is to convert the discrete to number and manually position it:

```
new_person$Home_city <- factor(new_person$Home_city,levels=levels(xDF$Home_city))

ggplot(data=xDF, aes(x=Home_city, y=age,color=sex))+
geom_boxplot()+
geom_label_repel(data=new_person, 
                 aes(x=as.numeric(Home_city)-0.15,label=name),
                 box.padding   = 0.35, 
                 point.padding = 0.5,
                 segment.color = 'grey50')
```

[image]